# Why lower half of uibutton didn't work when I change location of this button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

In my `viewController` I have `UILabel` with text, `UIButton` more under this label and `UIView` with 3 `UIButton`.

When I click button more I make `UILabel` with text higher and change location of `UIView` with `UIButton`. Before I click more button everything work good, but when I change location of `UIView` all three buttons:
   - work just upper half of these buttons.
I check if they are there by changing backgroundColor and they are there whole.
Code where I change location in by more button:

```
-(IBAction)moreButton:(id)sender{

[sender setHidden:YES];

NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:14]};

CGFloat height = 0.0;
if([_textLabel.text respondsToSelector:@selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)])
{
    height = CGRectGetHeight([_textLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(_textLabel.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)
                                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes context:nil]);

}
else
{
    height = [_textLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(_textLabel.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)].height;
}



CGFloat newScrollContentHeight = _scroll.contentSize.height + MAX(0, height-heightOfLabel);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
    _textLabel.alpha = 0.0;
    _scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scroll.contentSize.width, newScrollContentHeight - 120);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    CGRect frame = _textLabel.frame;
    _textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, height);
    CGFloat downPosition = _textLabel.frame.size.height - heightOfLabel;

    _buttonLess.frame = CGRectMake(_buttonMore.frame.origin.x, _buttonMore.frame.origin.y + downPosition, 80, 60);
    [_buttonLess setHidden:NO];
    [_buttonLess setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    self.buttonsView.frame = CGRectMake(frameButtonsView.origin.x, frameButtonsView.origin.y + downPosition, frameButtonsView.size.width, frameButtonsView.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
        _textLabel.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}];
}
```

buttonsView is the view which keep these buttons. Any idea why just upper half of buttons work?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is when you move your view it's mean your buttons on this will move too. So that, it's maybe cover by your background images or out of screen of device. Please check it(the code for reposition uiview) be careful.

Comment: Button has one label and imageView behind but I check when I click moreButton by coloring background of these buttons and it cover label and image so it mean nothing should cover it. Label with text too because it's above and lower part didtn't work not upper.

Comment: Button is cover by something(background images,or...).Sure for this reason. But now I use windows OS so that cannot run your code to find out the specific code line was created this reason.

Comment: I use autolayout and problem vanish. There are few others problems but it is another topic.